# my update button only updates first checked row not others

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I got the database to update, but it only does it for the first row selected not for the others.

```
     Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView6.Rows
        ' Selects the text from the TextBox
        Dim selectedcheck As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkselect"), CheckBox)

        If selectedcheck.Checked = True Then
            Dim id As Label = CType(row.FindControl("id"), Label)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compby", txtagent.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compdate", lbldate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtcomments.Text)


            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.updatetasks"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = conn

            conn.Open()

            cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery()

            conn.Close()
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

```
UPDATE dashboardtasks
       SET compby = @compby,
           comments = @comments,
           compdate = @compdate


       WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: `BeginExecuteNonQuery` returns before the command has finished executing. You certainly shouldn't be closing the connection immediately afterwards. If you want the command to complete, use the synchronous `ExecuteNonQuery`. If you want to continue using Asynchronous commands, you'll have to leave the connection open, capture the IAsyncResult returned from `BeginExecuteNonQuery`, and use it later in `EndExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Might need the stored procedure code to understand what it's doing. It seems you are updating a row by the key id. If id is unique then it will only update one record. Seeing as you are not looping through a series of id fields I'd say it works as expected. But seeing the stored procedure would help.

Comment: i added my stored procedure code, i am looping through the ids arent i?

Comment: i thought i was because the if statement is contained in the for each statement

Comment: I'd expect you to get an exception on the second (and subsequent) attempts to execute, since you're adding more and more parameters to the same `cmd` object. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: well when i changed it around i got a stored procedure has to many arguements : /

Comment: and when i leave it the way i have it it only updates one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the following to work:

```
  Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView6.Rows
        ' Selects the text from the TextBox
        Dim selectedcheck As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkselect"), CheckBox)

        If selectedcheck.Checked = True Then
            Dim id As Label = CType(row.FindControl("id"), Label)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()     '<---- Stop adding more and more parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compby", txtagent.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compdate", lbldate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtcomments.Text)


            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.updatetasks"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = conn

            conn.Open()

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() '<--- Don't use the asynchronous variant if you're not going to obey the contract

            conn.Close()
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

You would have gotten a nice exception telling you what you'd done wrong if you'd used the synchronous variant of `ExecuteNonQuery`, or obeyed the contract for Asynchronous methods (where you have to call `EndExecuteNonQuery` to discover the result of your SQL call.